# Repeated Background creates whitespace - android

Tags: android, background, repeat, removing-whitespace

My problem is a whitespace that creates itself when I put an image in the background.
I made a new icon set. Put an image there and cropped it so it has no white border. And when I create a new image view it works it has no border around itself. But when I put it as a background on repeat it creates a whitespace.
It looks like this:
I cant post an image so look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwNiz.gif

I am using a relative layout and I have created a file drawable and put an xml file in it in which  I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:src="@drawable/im" 
      android:gravity="center"  
      android:tileMode="mirror"/>
```

I tried it with 3 different pictures and it always does the whitespace when put on repeated background. 
I wanted the background to simply connect without any whitespace. 
Thanks in advance :)

I am using Eclipse.

Comment: take imageview instead of bitmap and set im as background of it

Comment: It still creates whitespace when I put it to fill the parent. So I guess the picture is wrong. But I cropped it and set padding to 0 when I created the icon-set. And in the preview while creating it it showed no white border. So how do I set the settings if I want it to have no whitespace?

Comment: instead of declaring directly pls take any layout eg. relative layout and than include imageview in that.Dont ever take child directly in the view try to add in parent.

Comment: I don't understand how can I put an image view directly in it. I have a relativelayout like this: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     > Then here I have the Imageview and then </RelativeLayout> But I have to set fill_parent if I want the Imageview to fill the layout don't I? This is pretty much my first time with XML though I did Java before.

Comment: I also tried to set the background as the image straight but it still does the whitespace as an `android:background="@drawable/im"` in the relative layout if that's what you meant.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same exact issue.  There's this ugly white padding around each tiled image.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you create a 9.png file and allow it to stretch to the edges? Looks like your bitmap is smaller than the space.

Comment: Well if you mean by writing `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in the bitmap it doesn't work it creates the whitespace again.

Comment: Nope. I mean using a "x.9.png" image file. This kind of image specifies where to stretch the image as needed so that it can fill the area with layout_gravity="fill". There is a tutorial at [http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html](here)

Comment: I am using Eclipse and I don't know how to do that in it. I searched it but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Justeagle11 You seem to have a bitmap that was drawn somewhere. You can open it in any tool that can edit png files and use it to create a draw9patch. Eclipse does not have this functionality.